# Leaflet: Placing markers/clusters in right side of map

Tags: d3.js, leaflet

I am working with a dataset where I am given time spent in locations or forms of transportation -  I am trying to attach the marker clusters for forms of transportation on a line below each other on the right side of the map, such that one can see how much time is spent on each kind of transport.

I tried doing this by finding the latlong of the different pixel positions, each time the map moves, like so:

```
var centerPoint = map.getSize().divideBy(2);

                    map.on('move', function(e) {

                            var name_array = [];

                            var multiplier_x = 0.95;
                            var multiplier_y = 0.8;
                            var index = 0;

                            layer_group.eachLayer(function (layer) {
                                if (layer.feature.properties.Name == 'Cycling' || layer.feature.properties.Name == 'Walking' || layer.feature.properties.Name == 'Driving' || layer.feature.properties.Name == 'Boating' || layer.feature.properties.Name == 'On a bus' || layer.feature.properties.Name == 'On a train'){

                                    if(!(layer.feature.properties.Name in name_array)){

                                        var targetPoint = centerPoint.add([centerPoint.x*multiplier_x, -centerPoint.y*(multiplier_y-index)]),
                                        targetLatLng = map.containerPointToLatLng(targetPoint);

                                        name_array[layer.feature.properties.Name] = targetLatLng;

                                        index += 0.2;
                                    }


                                    layer.setLatLng(name_array[layer.feature.properties.Name]);

                                }
                            });
                    });
```

The problem is that eventhough each transportation form is given a different location, they seem to cluster together anyway, and change between different clusters when the map is moved. Additionally, when moving the brush the map seems to move further and further to the left, as I am trying to fit the map to the bounds.

I don't know if it is possible to achieve what I am trying to - or if there maybe is another way of doing it, maybe by creating a seperate cluster group for the transportation, which I guess at least would make sure that the transportation isn't clustered with the locations?

Code: http://bl.ocks.org/skov94/e44fcebd282fe5eb4c708e8ba0af95d6

Comment: why don't you add the transportation clusters on an SVG overlay, no problem with the map moving

Comment: put the transportation markers in a separate GroupMarker layer, they influence the calculation of the `markers.getBounds()`

Comment: This sounds like a good solution, but I am pretty new to working with Leaflet, so I would be very grateful, if you could explain this more precisely or lead me to some documentation :) First of all, I am not sure how to make an SVG overlay, and the examples I've found seem to automatically scale and pan, where I guess that I just want it to stay in the same position. Also I don't understand whether I then will have to make a new markers variable, so that I can add the location markers to these, like this:`markers_location.addLayer(layer_group_location);
      svg.addLayer(markers_location);`

Comment: Or maybe I am misunderstanding what you mean? As I understand it you want to plot the transportation clusters at a given pixel, instead of at a given latlong - but how can you do that when a markerClusterGroup plots based on latlong?

Answer (score 1):

To plot them at a given pixel, based on a given latlng:

```
...
var topLeft = map._getNewPixelOrigin(map.getCenter(), map.getZoom());
var targetPoint = map.project(map.getCenter(), map.getZoom()).subtract(topLeft);
var targetLatLng = map.unproject(targetPoint);
...
```

By constantly calculating the new pixel origin, this ensures that the pixels and latLngs stay aligned even when panning